# ¿Cómo cargar video con formato h264 en etiqueta video de html5?

Tags: html5

Estoy intentando cargar un video y no se muestra, según la documentación de MDN puede ser porque el navegador no soporte el formato mp4 que inicialmente el video tiene y también leí que es mucho mejor utilizar videos con formato h264 pero estoy en la página de w3schools y solo encuentro como se carga videos mp4, ogg y otros formatos pero no encuentro ejemplos relacionados al formato h264.

En el html que tengo estoy poniendo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="conte-sidebar">
    <video width="241" height="371" autoplay muted>
        <source="RSC.h264" type="video/mp4">
        <source="RSC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**¿Esta bien la línea que tiene el formato de video h264?** ¿Talvez es un problema de xampp el que no se pueda visualizar los videos?

Comment: Si fuese cosa del navegador, con poner un texto alterno dentro del tag video, después de los source, lo sabrías (porque saldría el texto). ¿Qué pasa si sólo dejas el source del h264? ¿Funciona? Hasta donde recuerdo, ese stream solía requerir un plugin del lado del navegador y tocaba usar la etiqueta embed, pero ya soy un viejales y habría que revisar, por eso la prueba sugerida...

Comment: Mira cuando solo ponía el video en mp4 solo me salían los controles para el video pero no se reproducía y también no había tiempo de duración, con el video en formato h264 no salía algo y visiblemente parecería como que se  hubiera comentado la parte de la etiqueta del video